# Save KDB+/q table on a Mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kdb, pyq

I'm new to q and I'm trying to save a file on my **Mac**. Currently using Jupyter Notebook if that makes a difference.

A quick table:

```
t:([] c1:`a`b`c; c2:1.1 2.2 3.3)
```

I first extract my current location by using `\cd` and i get: `"/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/q"`

but when I try

```
`:/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/q set t
```

I get:

```
evaluation error:

type

  [1]  (.q.set)


  [0]  `:/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/q set t
                                ^
```

I'm following examples from "Q for Mortals" from the kx website:

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/#11-starting-q

For easy find use cmd (or ctrl) + F and find "t set t"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a different filename, like `t`? `\`:/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/t set t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers to this question, depending on whether you want to save your file as a **flat** table, or a **splayed** table.

If you want to save you table as a **flat** table, you need to give a file name for your table. Currently, you're just giving it the directory that you want to save it in. So for instance, the following should work for you:

```
`:/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/q/t set t
```

If instead, you want to save your table as a **splayed** table, then you will need to pass it a directory (ideally, one that is not already being used by the file system). To do this, you will pass set a file path with a **trailing forward slash**. So the following should work for you:

```
`:/Users/Gorlomi/Documents/q/t/ set t
```

Comment: Quick addtion the latter part of the answer, if you want to save it as a splayed table, you're going to need to enumerate it!